# ApostoprheCMS - how to use jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, apostrophe-cms

I wonder what is the best way to add jQuery-ui in my ApostropheCMS project. Now I have a minified jquery-ui file in my assets and I push the asset in this way:
  `self.pushAsset('script', 'jquery-ui.min');`

It works, but I don't like this solution because my js file is quite big. Is there a better way to do this? I noticed that there is this file in apostorphe repo but I'm not sure if I can use this somehow
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/main/lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/vendor/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI is already included in Apostrophe-CMS's assets by default. There's a couple versions that are used depending on the version of jQuery you specify (you can, and probably should, tell Apostrophe to use jQuery 3 by setting jQuery: 3 as an option in apostrophe-assets). You should be able to test this by using one of jQuery UI's methods like draggable - without adding your own jQuery UI scripts, that method should still be available on any elements you retrieve with jQuery (just tested on my own installation).